# unable to get data from $q into scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm trying to bind some data being returned from an API to my scope using promises with $q, I am able to pull the data from the server without any issue (I can see JSON being returned using fiddler) however the $scope variable remains empty, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Code:

toDoListService.js

```
 app.factory("toDoListService", function ($http, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        return {
            get: function () {

                $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo/' }).
                    success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
});
```

toDoListController.js

```
app.controller("toDoListController", function($scope, toDoListService){
      $scope.toDoList = toDoListService.get();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should put `var deferred = $q.defer();` in your `get` function, so that every `get` has it's own deferred object.

Second what `get` actually returns is a promise. So you need to access you data in this way:

```
app.controller("toDoListController", function($scope, toDoListService){
    toDoListService.get().then(function(data){
           $scope.toDoList = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your `$scope.toDoList` is bound to a promise. This means of binding used to work, but was deprecated in, I think, 1.2.

As Michael suggests, you must do:

```
app.controller("toDoListController", function($scope, toDoListService){
  toDoListService.get().then(function(data){
    $scope.toDoList = data;
  });
});
```

Also, using `$q` is not required here at all, as `$http` returns a promise anyway. Therefore, you could just do:

```
app.factory("toDoListService", function ($http){       
   return {
     get: function () {
        return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo/' });
     }
   };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by using this:

**toDoListService.js**

```
app.factory("toDoListService", function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo/' });
        }
    }
});
```

**toDoListController.js**

```
app.controller("toDoListController", function($scope, toDoListService) {
    toDoListService.get().then(function(response){
        $scope.toDoList = response.data;
        return response;
    });
});
```

Be sure to return `response` in your success callback, otherwise chained promises would not receive it.